# Generate sine wave with PWM in C-program - STM32F100RB

Tags: c, pwm, sine, stm32f10x

I am trying to generate sine waves from my microcontroller (STM32F100RB) by using PWM in C. I would like to generate sine waves and to do so I would need to variate the pulse width. I am trying to program multiple different duty cycles to create these sine waves. So far this code only provides one constant duty cycle of 50 %. Does anyone know how I would be able to make multiple, different duty cycles?

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

#include stm32f10x_gpio.h

#include stm32f10x_rcc.h

#include stm32f10x_tim.h

int main(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
  TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;
  uint32_t Prescaler, Period;

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);


  Prescaler = (SystemCoreClock / 400000);
  Period = 20000;

  TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = (uint16_t)(Prescaler - 1);
  TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = (uint16_t)(Period - 1);
  TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up; 
  TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0; // Not used
  TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0; // Not used
  TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);


  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = (uint16_t)(Period / 2); // 50%
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputNState = TIM_OutputNState_Enable;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPolarity_Low;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCIdleState = TIM_OCIdleState_Set;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCNIdleState = TIM_OCIdleState_Reset;

  TIM_OC1Init(TIM1, &TIM_OCInitStructure);


  TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);

  TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM1, ENABLE);

  while(1);
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
 void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{

  while (1)
  {
  }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Why have you put . in front of every #?

Comment: Perhaps to update duty cycle after each cycle or at constant sampling time.

Comment: This is very much a read the datasheet and figure out how to use the PWM peripheral situation.

Comment: First off, you should organize your code a bit.  Create a function called 'setDutyCycle' that takes care of setting the duty cycle.  Separate out other functions into their higher-level functionality as well.  This will help a lot.  Direct register manipulation is fast, but completely incomprehensible after you have written it.  This [article](https://hackaday.com/2016/02/12/embed-with-elliot-audio-playback-with-direct-digital-synthesis/) on direct digital synthesis should help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change the period ?

One line in your code is:

```
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = (uint16_t)(Period / 2); // 50%
```

Change the divider to suite your needs. For example to achieve 33% of duty cycle:

```
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = (uint16_t)(Period / 3); // 33%
```

This is mostly guessing because the code you posted is very much unreadable.

Comment: I fixed it now! But changing the period will still just give me the one constant duty cycle of example 33%. I´m trying to code so I can set up different duty cycles from example first 33% then on to 50% and then on to 67% with a time interval of examaple 100 ms between each of the different duty cycles.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is change the Pulse period at the end of each cycle (PWM_Period).

On ARM processors this is easy to do..... 
     Switch on end of cycle interrupts 
     Write an interrupt service method to step the pulse cyclically through a table of values representing the sine (or other) wave you wish to generate.

In order to switch on interrupts, you need to set up the NVIC.

Using DMA in cyclic mode you can let the DMA cycle through your table. Look at some of the higher level ARM processors with DAC. The code you want will be very similar.

Then use STM_Cube to write most of the code for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with your code, but you have a line:

```
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = (uint16_t)(Period / 2); // 50%
```

This line is somehow setting your duty cycle.  It looks like you are using some library.  Within the timer, there is a duty cycle register, I don't know what it is called, but all timers with PWM modules have them.  Find it.

Floating point version:

```
void setDutyCycle(float dutyCyclePercentage){
    <duty cycle register> = (unsigned int)(<period register> * dutyCyclePercentage);
}
```

Fixed point version:

```
void setDutyCycle(signed int dutyCyclePercentageFixed){
    <duty cycle register> = q15_mul(<period register>,dutyCyclePercentage);
}
```

I like to use libmathq15, which is targeted at 16-bit processors, but it will work just fine on all architectures, just with less advantage.

You might also check out http://www.forembed.com/how-fixed-point-math-works/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really read through your code.

Think of the PWM output as a one bit DAC. As the duty cycle varies from 0% to 100%, the voltage of your "DAC" varies from 0 to VCC.

So, you need to somehow create a data stream that represents a sine wave (numerically), and feed that data stream into the duty cycle register of the PWM. You need to update the PWM duty cycle register once per duty cycle period. The timing must be managed so that the new duty cycle takes effect after the current one expires.

Since your code is running on a micro-controller, don't try to execute trig  functions. What you will want to do is create a software DDS. You use a variable as a phase accumulator. The phase of a sine wave increases linearly, and wraps back to zero at 2*PI. So you can just increment an unsinged integer type (this is your phase accumulator). Use how ever many bits you want in your phase accumulator.

Then take the top 8 bits of your phase, and use that to enter a lookup table. The lookup table will give you your output data. You can use more bits for your lookup table, but the size will quickly become unmanageable.

The lookup table should be pre-computed on a PC or using a spreadsheet or something, and pasted into your program prior to compilation.

Hope that helps.